# Design a layout like a dialog comes from the bottom side in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design layout which contains one button which is on the top side of the screen when we click on the button it should open a layout which comes from the bottom side like a keypad.

But no idea how to do this?

please share your ideas to do this.

Screen shot of layout:

[image]

when i click on that drop down button , another layout will come from download with a size of virtual keypad.

Thanks,
Ammu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation can help you to do this:

```
private void initPopup() 
{

    final TransparentPanel popup = (TransparentPanel) findViewById(R.id.popup_window);

    //  Start out with the popup initially hidden.
    popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.popup_show);
    animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.popup_hide);

    final Button   showButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup_button);
    final Button   hideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hide_popup_button);
    showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            popup.startAnimation( animShow );
            showButton.setEnabled(false);
            hideButton.setEnabled(true);
    }});

    hideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popup.startAnimation( animHide );
            showButton.setEnabled(true);
            hideButton.setEnabled(false);
            popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }});


    final TextView locationName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_name);
    final TextView locationDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_description);

    locationName.setText("Animated Popup");
    locationDescription.setText("Animated popup is created by Arun nu solla mattaen"
                                + " Transparent layout is used on this example, and animation xml is also used"
                                + " on this example. Have a Good day guys.");
}
```

See this [example](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17405180/Popup.zip.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hey i have already saw that...using that code the layout which comes from the bottom will occupying the entire layout. I just want it small height

Answer (score 4):

Try SlidingDrawer as it is used [Example](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html) and for more about that is obviously [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)